# Compactness of unitary group

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

How to see the unitary group is not compact in norm topology of $B(H)$ for infinite dimensional Hilbert space? What if norm topology is replaced by SOT?

Answer (score 5):

Say $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z}$ is an orthonormal basis. For each $k$ there is a unitary operator $T_k$ with $$T_ke_0=e_{k},$$ $$T_ke_k=e_0,$$ and $$T_ke_j=e_j\quad(j\ne0,k).$$Hence $\|T_k-T_j\|=\|T_0-T_1\|>0$ for $j\ne k$, so the group is not compact in the norm topology.

And $T_ne_1$ has no norm-convergent subsequence, so the group is also not compact in the SOT.

(Not that you asked , but the same example shows that the unitary group is not even *closed* in  the WOT, since $T_k\to0$ in the WOT...)

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: but how this map can be unitaty, if it is not surjective? this is an isometry, but not unitary operator.

Comment: @grigoriistepanov Good point - fixed

Comment: @peterag Oops. Yes, typo - thanks...